# Where was "St. Joseph, F1.T." or possibly "St. Joseph, FI. T." shown on a postmark dated Dec 8, 1837?

Tags: 19th-century

My best guess is that "T." stands for "Territory".  I'm thinking Missouri or Michigan as likely locations. I also note that Michigan became a state in January 1837.  This letter was from an M.L. Cavert to "Uncle" Matthew Sherwood in Saratoga County, NY regarding a recent shipment of a tub of butter from Sherwood. Many thanks for the quick replies.  Florida sounds like a very likely answer.

As a newbie, I find I'm not allowed to transmit an image yet--sorry!

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy and Family History SE.  It would probably get better answers if there was an image of the postmark to look at, and some context would help as well. You mention Michigan, but don't explain why it's relevant.

Comment: I too would love to see a digital image of the item that contains or refers to the postmark. Additional context (information "about" the source) would also be helpful.

Comment: "As a newbie ..." Other than attracting rep, there are a couple of ways to work around that problem. You could upload the image to a public album (like Picasa, for example); then post that link. Or, circle/friend a Genealogy.SE member with rep on G+ or FaceBook; share the image with that person and have them edit/add the image.

Answer (score 6):

It's most likely "Fl. T", ie the Florida Territory, created 1822 and made a state in 1845.

The reason you never heard of the city of St Joseph in Florida is because it got hit by yellow fever and abandoned in 1841.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Joseph,_Florida

Comment: Gene J, will this work to view the image?: https://plus.google.com/photos/102170481305614133944/albums/5805189658444963089/5805189709942552802#photos/102170481305614133944/albums/5805189658444963089                    David

Comment: @user418: 1. You wrote your comment in the wrong place. 2. You should write an @ before GeneJ's name so he get's notified about your comment. 3. No, that link doesn't work, you have to make the image public.

Comment: @gene Oh, the learning curve.  Thanks for the advice, Lennart.  The above link should be public now.

Comment: @GeneJ: ping. ^^^